# returning JSP value to AJAX call

Tags: java, ajax, jsp

I have made an AJAX call to a JSP, which in turn calls a Java method in a separate Java class. All files are in the same folder.

For some reason, I can't get the correct value returned to AJAX. It simply prints the whole JSP content.

JavaScript:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onload = function() {
    if(true){
        alert('hello!');
        var response = xhr.responseText;
        alert(response);
        document.getElementById('newgame').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;

    }
};

xhr.open('GET', 'javaconnect.jsp', true);
xhr.send(null);
```

JSP:

```
<%@ page import="com.example.Server"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>

  <%
   Server tc = new Server();
      out.print(tc.highScore());

  %>


</body>
</html>
```

Java class:

```
    package com.example;
     public class Server {


    public String highScore() {


        return "hello!!!";

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use a Servlet to make the control layer in place of jsp that instantiates the Server class, like:

```
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet (HttpServletRequest request,
                                HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {

        Server tc = new Server();
        String txt = tc.highScore();

        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(txt);
    }

}
```

Do not forget to map the servlet and change the url of the ajax call.
You can test call

Comment: Just to clarify since I am quite new to this, you suggest I use a servlet INSTEAD of a jsp? The URL in the ajax call will simply be the name of the servlet file no? Just like I did with the jsp.

Comment: If your web project uses Servlet 3.0 is simple:
@WebServlet("/my-servlet") // <-------- mapping Servlet
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
  ...
}
The url would be http://localhost:<port>/<name-your-app>/my-servlet
But uses Servlet 2.5 you need mapping the Servlet in web.xml file, Here's an example 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/webapp/configureservlet.html